# How to center text inside a float right?

Tags: html, css

I have a div which is supposed to be floating right (and it is) but I want some text inside that div to center relative to the float right, how do I do this?

I tried to center it like this:

```
<div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon center">Verified:</span>                  
</div>
```

But it's not working.

Here's a fiddle of the situation:

http://jsfiddle.net/rLtb7dc7/1/

Comment: Just add `text-align:center;` to the parent div (`.floatRight`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rLtb7dc7/2/)**

Add `display: block` with / without `margin`, the content will be aligned to center

**CSS:**

```
.center {
    text-align: center;
    margin:0 auto;
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: I don't think that `margin: 0 auto` is really required in this case. don't you?

Comment: @sachin: I too think the same, that's why mentioned "with / without margin " in my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this css :

```
.floatRight {
    float: right;
}

.formTitle {
    font-weight: bold;
}

.input-group{
    text-align:center;
}
```

You won't need the center class anymore and you'll avoid repeating rules.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
.floatRight {
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
    width: 100%;
}
span{text-align: center;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just using all available Space inside the floated element by setting display to block. And set text-align: center;

```
   .input-group {
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
    }
```